I can't center Paragraph and the text below it with flexbox
Hi I am currently working on a simple project from freecodecamp tribute page. I want to mak
I am trying to center paragraph and the header without moving the nav bar. I tried using flexbox I am fairly new.
I also want to center my image later on. My text-align doesnt work I also tried that.
Here is the HTML and CSS:


body {
  background: white;
  font-family: Fira Code;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  margin: 30px 8px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #eee;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.center-h1 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  margin-block: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  color: #dfdfe2;
  margin: 0 0.2rem;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  display: block;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #dfdfe2;
  color: #606096;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li a {
  color: #606096;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#image {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 60%;
}

#img-caption {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.tribute-info {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #dfdfe2;
}
<main id="main">
  <header>
    <div class="center-h1">
      <h1 id="title">Paragraph Center</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">INFO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Accomplishments</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section class="main-part">
    <div class="img-div">
      <img id="image" src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/tribute-page-main-image.jpg" alt="Photo of Pepe">
      <figcaption id="img-caption">Paragraph from the left 3 third.</figcaption>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="tribute-info" class="tribute-info">
    <div class="section-header">
      <h2>Here's a time line of Pepe's Life:</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="unordered-list">
      <ul>
        <li><strong>2000</strong> - P Born</li>
        <li><strong>2000</strong> - P Born</li>
        <li><strong>2000</strong> - P Born</li>
        <li><strong>2000</strong> - P Born</li>
        <li><strong>2000</strong> - P Born</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <p>If you want to learn more : <a id="tribute-link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Borlaug" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a></p>
  </section>
</main>




You can't really center something like that. The h1 can be centered inside its container, but if its container goes from the left to the nav element, it can't easily be centered relative to the width of the entire page. A workaround would be to apply position: absolute; to the h1, and then we get the problem that if the page isn't wide enough, the h1 and nav overlap.
For this reason, the best solution is to place the navigation above or below the text, or decide to place the nav on the right and the text on the left with a display flex set to flex direction column and justify content set to space-between.
You're doing a pretty good job of HTML semantics but there were still a couple excessive wrappers and the image and figcaption were inside a section instead of a figure tag.
Another thing to note is the use of header, main, footer. You shouldn't embed these inside each other. The body element is supposed to contain a header, main and footer element below each other. The header contains the navigation, the main contains the page's contents, and the footer is in case you want to put some links or text at the bottom of the page.


body {
  background: white;
  font-family: Fira Code;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  margin: 30px 8px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #eee;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
  align-items: right;
}

#title {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  margin-block: 0;
  float: right;
}

nav>a {
  color: #606096;
  margin: 0 0.2rem;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  display: block;
}

nav>a:hover {
  background-color: #dfdfe2;
  color: #606096;
  cursor: pointer;
}

figure#pepe-image {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

figure#pepe-image>image {
  padding-top: 100px;
  width: 60%;
}

figure#pepe-image>figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.tribute-info {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #dfdfe2;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pepe's life</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="title">Paragraph Center</h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">Info</a>
      <a href="#">Accomplishments</a>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <figure id="pepe-image">
      <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/images/tribute-page-main-image.jpg" alt="Photo of Pepe">
      <figcaption>Paragraph from the left 3 third.</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <section class="tribute-info">
      <h2>Here's a time line of Pepe's Life:</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><strong>2000</strong> - P Born</li>
        <li><strong>2000</strong> - P Born</li>
        <li><strong>2000</strong> - P Born</li>
        <li><strong>2000</strong> - P Born</li>
        <li><strong>2000</strong> - P Born</li>
      </ul>
      <p>If you want to learn more: <a id="tribute-link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Borlaug" target="_blank">Wikipedia</a></p>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer>Coder Pirate © 2024</footer>
</body>

</html>



If you got any questions or if this doesn't answer your question, leave a reply and let me know! I also want to say, welcome to Stack overflow.

I think I understand thank you very much. I mostly use sections for different sections for my css file.
I tought I could use sections as in different "section blocks" so I can easily code and it would be more readible. I didnt know I needed those inside figure thank you.
Is it possible to put those figure-img and figcaption inside a section block ?

I changed a lot since you updated my code but now when I change the Nav bar it overflow from my section ( main ). Example in your code
